# Reset ngModel values on ngIf in angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms, angular2-services

I have a model which is an array element. I want to clear the values of each element on ngIf condition.Please find below HTML :

```
         <div *ngIf="flag" >
            <table id="table" class="table table-hover table-bordered  table-mc-light-blue">
               <thead>
                   <tr>
                       <th>col 1</th>
                       <th>col 2</th>
                   </tr>
                </thead>
                <tr *ngFor="let item of collection;">
                     <td>{{item.col1}}</td>
                     <td>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="item.col2" #input="ngModel" name="input-{{i}}">
                     </td>
                 </tr>
             </table>
         </div>
```

On **flag** set to false, I want to clear all values of the **collection**.
There is an option of initializing **collection**, but I don't want to do that as I have several such collections.

Any help would be appreciable!!

Comment: when does the `flag` value will change and on what event?

Comment: Actually, there is no event,I have that flag variable bound to radio button as ngmodel. On change of radio button i am showing the content

Comment: Thank you. . . .. .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input type="radio" (change)="resetForm()"/>


resetForm(){
     if(!this.flag){
          this.collection = new Array()
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the "event" or method call that causes the flag to be set to false?

This is the method call where you'll also want to clear the collection.

Something like this:

```
public toggleFlag() {
  this.expandFlag = !this.expandFlag;
  this.collection = [];
}
```

Comment: Actually, there is no event,I have that **flag** variable bound to radio button as ngmodel. On change of radio button i am showing the content

Answer (score 0):

In your component:

```
ngDoCheck() {
    if (!this.flag) {
        this.collection = [];
    }
}
```

And you have to implement `DoCheck` like this:

```
export class myClass implements OnInit, DoCheck {
```

Basically, this is a listener that trigger at every change that happens, and here we check that `this.flag` is false and we empty the `collection` array element.

Comment: It worked but ngDoCheck was getting called multiple times, so I opted for (change) event

Comment: @JayakrishnanGounder Oh, ok. I am glad that helped in anyway.. ;) Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

For your simple example, if you convert your table into a component, then you can use the OnDestroy lifecycle event to clear the model values for that component.

```
ngOnDestroy() {this.collection = [];}
```

I have a situation where it's more complicated, so I've asked a similar question at [Angular 2+ - Set ngModel to null when ngIf causes hide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50979046/angular-2-set-ngmodel-to-null-when-ngif-causes-hide)

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a solution for my situation that would also work for this one.  The following project has a directive that binds to the ngModel and uses the directive's OnDestroy event to trigger setting the ngModel to null. It could be modified to set the value to anything or you could create a variation that would set arrays to empty.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4uwdmi?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html